# True Error of a binary classifier

Tags: machine-learning

For a given classifier h, How is the true error over a distribution D defined?
\begin{align*}
L_D(h) &= \sideset{\mathbb{E}}{}{}_{x,y \sim D} \Pr[h(x) \neq y] \\ &=
\sideset{\mathbb{E}}{}{}_{x,y \sim D}
\begin{cases}
\Pr[y \neq 0|x] & \text{if } h(x) = 0, \\
\Pr[y \neq 1|x] & \text{if } h(x) = 1.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

I saw these two formulae here [Showing that Bayes classifier is optimal](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/72295/showing-that-bayes-classifier-is-optimal/72297#72297?newreg=0aa24bbb68b4439d890d45d80b888a53) Are these two equivalent?

Comment: Yes, the two formulas are equivalent. Now try to see why this is the case. The first step is to understand the notations.

Comment: Expanding the first one, we get Pr[h(x)=1, y=0] + Pr[h(x)=0, y=1]. If we assume h(x) = 0, that is Pr[h(x)=0] = 1. The term boils down to Pr[y≠0/h(x)=0] which is different from Pr[y≠0/x] right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line should read
$$
\Pr_{x,y \sim D}[h(x) \neq y].
$$
(This is assuming that the classifier is deterministic.)

We can sample $x,y \sim D$ in two steps: first sample $x \sim D'$, and then sample $y \sim C_x$, where $C_x$ is a distribution depending on $x$.

The second line expresses the idea
$$
\operatorname*{\mathbb{E}}_{x \sim D'} \Pr_{y \sim C_x}[y \neq h(x)]
$$
in an elaborate way.

Both of these are the same, and equal to
$$
\operatorname*{\mathbb{E}}_{x \sim D'} \operatorname*{\mathbb{E}}_{y \sim C_x} 1_{h(x) \neq y}.
$$

Comment: So should there not be a term, Pr(x) multiplied in the RHS which will account for the probability of sampling that specific x from the distribution D'. I agree that it doesn't have anything to do with the classifier h and hence while proving that the classifier is most optimal we can ignore that.

Comment: It’s there, hiding in the expectation operator.

Comment: I am bit confused with the notation of expectation operator. Can you please clarify if the two expectation operators defined the same?

Comment: Exactly the same. Expectation has only one meaning.

Comment: Please explain me this. Pr[y≠h(x)] = summation over all x Pr[y≠h(x)/x]*Pr[x]. I can right the term as E[Pr[y≠h(x)/x]]. This expectation is over all possible x correct? How does the outer expectation account for this?

Comment: In $\Pr[y \neq h(x)]$, the probability is only over $h$; the two values $x,y$ have already been decided. I suspect that the author intended to write $\Pr[y \neq h(x)]$ rather than the clumsy $\mathbb{E}_{x,y} \Pr[y \neq h(x)]$.

Comment: The expectation operator incorporates $\Pr[x]$.